ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css/bootstrap.min.css'
I've tried almost all the solutions exist on stackoverflow and few other channels but I couldn't get this resolved. File already exists on path but it couldn't find it. Same behavior on the server during deployment. I can make it work by disabling STATICFILE_STORAGE with "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage" and adding entries like:
WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False
WHITENOISE_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

But I am not sure if this is solution.
Please assist as I've checked many times over an over to my settings. Looking forward for your kind help.
